# Странное поведение метода jQuery prepend()/prependTo() - возможно баг

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

[image]Причина этого вопроса и собственно сам вопрос:
На HTML странице используется двухуровневый список(на первом уровне вложенности - "уровни иерархии", на втором уровне вложенности - элементы "уровня иерархии").
Этот список отображается на основе иерархической структуры данных следующим образом:

```
text = '<ul id="editor">'
       + '<li class="category">'
       + '<div class="name">'
         + '<h2>Главная цель: ' 
           + '<span class="editable level">'+ jsData[0]['items'][0]['name'] +'</span>'
         + '</h2>'
       + '</div>'
       + '<ul id="levels">'
       + '</ul>'
     + '</li></ul>';
var hierarchyObj = $(text);
var levelsObj = hierarchyObj.find('#levels'); //object copy or not? [it is reference &]
var deleteObj = $('<span class="delete" title="delete item"></span>').click(removeItem);
var curLevelObj;
var itemsHTML;
for (var i = 1; i < jsData.length; i++)
{
    //HTML описание уровня
    var levelAliasHTML = jsData[i]['alias']; //alias for hierarchical level
    text += '<li id="level'+ i +'" class="detail">'
    + '<span class="remove" title="remove level">[remove]</span>'
    + '<span class="description"> Уровень '
    + '<span class="order">'+ i +'</span>(' + levelAliasHTML +'):</span>'
    + '</li>';
    curLevelObj = $(text);
    //HTML описание элементов уровня
    text = '<ol>';
    for (var j = 0; j < jsData[i]['items'].length; j++)
    {
        text += '<li class="level'+ i +'"><span class="editable item">'
    + jsData[i]['items'][j]['name'] +'</span>{'
    + jsData[i]['items'][j]['id'] 
    +'}<div class="right">'
    + jsData[i]['items'][j]['weight'] 
    +'</div></li>';
    }
    text += '</ol>';

    itemsHTML = $(text);
    //на первой итерации(i=1) deleteObj ни с чем не связан
    //и добавляется без проблем к каждому узлу
    //на второй и последующих эта операция ведёт себя так как будто 
    //deleteObj связан с предыдущим узлом, в который он добавлялся
    //и посленее добавление из предыдущей итерации отменяется
    deleteObj.prependTo(itemsHTML.children());
}
levelsObj.append(curLevelObj);
hierarchyObj.appendTo("#wrapper");
```

Comment: Видимо(по коду) - это баг ))

Comment: какой ужас. вы бы хоть fiddle сделали,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

операции типа prepend/append и прочие **не клонируют объект**. делайте

```
deleteObj.clone(true).prependTo(itemsHTML.children());
```

при массовом добавлении клонируют, но указатель переменной становится равным последнему добавлению что вы и имеете. как-то так.

Comment: тоже пришел к выводу, что объект надо клонировать, но хотел узнать мнения экспертов, спасибо, вопрос исчерпан